How to resize an image and keep backround empty using OpenCV
I have the following 256x256 image:

I want to resize it to 100x100 pixels using OpenCV:
img = cv2.imread('image.png')

p = 100/256
new_width = int( img.shape[1] * p ) 
new_height = int( img.shape[0] * p ) 

resized = cv2.resize(img, (new_width, new_height))

What I get after execution of the code above:

As you can see, its background colour changed to black. But I want to keep the backgound empty. What can I do?

you need to load the image with 4 channels. 3 for the colors 1 for transparency/alpha.
im = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)  should work.
if you allready have data:
im = cv2.cvtColor(rgb_data, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)

you WILL get artefacts at edges between transparent and opaque areas. if you're lucky, those edges will just appear darker, but they may be tinted with wild colors. that depends on what colors the transparent pixels happen to be given.

This question is similar to: Set white background for a png instead of transparency with OpenCV. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try read the image with cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED:
img = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

Reading with cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED to ensure the alpha channel (transparency) is preserved.

that's still not going to solve the artefacts that'll happen due to the resize()
